# UDP Cannot Assign Requested Address

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, datagram, poco-libraries

I want to open a Datagramsocket and send some packets to my network device.
However when i use the following cood an exception is thrown saying: 
`Cannot Assign Requested Address: 192.168.1.114:1900`

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("192.168.1.114",1900);
Poco::Net::DatagramSocket dgs(sa);
std::string text = "hello";
dgs.sendBytes(text.data(),text.size());
```

What's the problem here. I also use a udp testing software to test the receiving end if it's capable to receive udp packets on this port and it works, however with the poco code from above it does not work.

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `Poco` but you must `bind` to a **local** address and port, then your `sendto` will send your packet *from* that local address:port to the *remote* address and port.

Comment: This answer is correct. You may bind to a local IP address, although it isn't necessary, and if you want UDP 'connected' semantics you must connect() to the remote IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs. Likely `sa` should be the local address and the remote address is to be specified somewhere else.

UDP doesn't have the notion of connection so there's no reason to bind the socket to a single remote address. A UDP socket can send and receive to/from any remote socket.

Comment: I see, How can i specify the IP:port of the target device then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Poco library. Check the documentation/examples.